# Manage/Add file formats for Finder preview

Tags: finder, preview, quicklook

How should Finder be configured to preview specific file formats? For example, I have a .frag file and Finder recognises it as an OpenGL Shading Language Fragment Shader. Finder is able to show a preview of the code in the .frag file as text without any syntax highlighting. I also have a .osl file and Finder is not able to recognise it as an Open Shading Language Shader. Finder is then not able to show a preview of the code in the .osl file. Is there a way to extend Finder's recognised file formats so that it can also display a preview of the code inside the .osl file?

What I have tried is using different QuickLook Generator apps like Syntax Highlight, QLColorCode, QLStephen and Glance that can be installed with homebrew. Is there a way to add file formats in these quicklook apps?

The only method that gave somewhat satisfactory results was one where the Terminal is used with the mdls command to get metadata on files. With Terminal the desired file's kMDItemContentType is queried and then manually added to a Info.plist file of the QuickLook Generator app. The result I got was with the QLColorCode app but although the Finder preview panel was able to display text for the .osl file it was in a visually bad way. The file's code is displayed/previewed within a large "page with folded upper right corner" icon. This is a bad preview of the file's code because it is displayed in a tiny font size at the top of the "page with folded upper right corner" icon. Hitting the space bar on the file, however, does open a quicklook window with readable code with no syntax highlighting.

Comment: What is your macOS exactly? It might also help if you add screenshots exampling the undesirable Finder preview you get with some of the code files and the acceptable view you get for the rest.